# jqgrid uidatepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, uidatepicker

I'm having a problem with the DatePicker implementção with jqGrid.

I got it using editoptions:{dataInit:functiondate} for the DatePicker is instantiated.
User clicks on the field and called datepicker and perfectly.

When the datepicker is appearing and click directly on the close button of the form.
The form closes and the datepicker was open.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A demo of this at http://www.the-di-lab.com/demo/apples does not seem to have the problem; perhaps if you compare your code to theirs you will find a solution?